# Difference between ls and rosls?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Difference between roscd and cd?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264680/difference-between-ls-and-rosls?/) by [Disha](https://answers.ros.org/users/30901/disha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-06-24

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-06-25**:
rosls allows you to view the contents of a package, stack, or location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[wiki/rosbash](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-25**:
PS: it would be nice if you could spent at least *some* time searching before asking such really basic questions.

We're here to help, so any question is welcome, but you'll even save yourself quite some time if you just google for these kind of things, instead of having to wait 7h for an answer.